# can't play a sound in Meteor.js app

Tags: meteor, html5-audio

I can't play sound in a Meteor app. Without Meteor it works.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
// counter starts at 0
Session.setDefault("counter", 0);

Template.hello.helpers({
counter: function () {
  return Session.get("counter");
}
});

Template.hello.events({
'click button': function () {
 new Audio('/root/test/audio.wav').play();
  // increment the counter when button is clicked
  Session.set("counter", Session.get("counter") + 1);
 }
});
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
Meteor.startup(function () {
// code to run on server at startup
});
}
```

I also tried 'audio.wav' as the path because it is in de root directory of the app. (test)

I hope someone can help. Thanks.
Greetings Joris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out: I put the audio file in public folder